# SQL Server 2008 AND SSIS - Max Number of Columns

Tags: sql-server, ssis

What is the maximum number of columns witin SQL Server 2008?  I know at least in 2005 the limitations were related to row size, does this still apply?

Right after I define and populate this ridiculously wide table I will need to write an SSIS package against it.  Are there different limitations for SSIS for number of columns than there are for SQL Server?

In essence I have a very large number of attributes about an entity that for a number of reasons will need to be stored on one table and then extracted in that same columns wide format and I want to make sure what the rules are within SQL Server 2008 and SSIS 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 has a max for Wide and NonWide. Unless you've taken special steps to use sparse columns, you've got a NonWide table.

> Columns per nonwide table   1,024
>   Columns per wide table     30,000

Row size limitations (with a caveat, see details in specs below):

> Bytes per row  8,060

- [Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)
- More on [Wide and NonWide at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186986.aspx).

Comment: All true, but what about the SSIS side of the question?

Comment: This definitely asnwers my SQL Server question.  I will mark it as the answer if I don't get any responses soon on the SSIS question.